# Solving an expectation related to CIR process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, moment-generating-functions

I encounter the following question

> Let $X$ satisfy the SDE $$dX_s=k(\alpha-X_s)ds+\sigma\sqrt{X_s}dW_s$$ for $s\geq t$ with $X_t=x$, where $k,\alpha,\sigma$ are positive constants.  Find the conditional expectation $$u(t,x)=\mathbb{E}[exp(\beta X_T)|\mathcal{F}_t]$$, where $\beta$ is a positive constant satisfying $k-\sigma^2\beta/2>0$.

$X$ obviously follows a CIR process and therefore $X_t$ has a chi-squared distribution and $u(t,x)$ is just the mgf of a chi-sq distribution (times some deterministic function).  My question is: In an exam, if we don't know the density function of $X_t$, nor the mgf of $X_t$, is there any other way to solve for $u(t,x)$?

Comment: If you know almost nothing, Feynman Kac formula and try the pde formulation. Or try to write it as a (sum of) squared OU.

Comment: No I would certainly not recommend using the pdf of $X$, I would try to use Itô's lemma and try to see if there is an ODE coming from some calculations and some martingale property. Best regards